# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

[Sitecore Stack Exchange's graduation election](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Marek Musielak]

[image: Pete Navarra]

[image: Richard Seal]

Marek Musielak and Pete Navarra will be joining Richard Seal on the moderation team. Richard has already been serving as a pro-tem moderator on the site since the site went into beta in 2016. (Since this was the site's graduation election, any pro-tem mods who wished to continue serving as moderators needed to be reelected.) Please thank them all for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking jammykam and Mark Cassidy, who will be stepping down after several years of serving as pro-tem moderators:

[image: jammykam]

[image: Mark Cassidy]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5652197508382720).

Comment: Thank you all for supporting the Sitecore Community!